# Android calendar header shows wrong month-year in material-calendarview

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I'm using [Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) library to show a specific month. I used `setMinimumDate()` and `setMaximumDate()` to get this functionality.

My XML code is:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mcv_showOtherDates="none"
    app:mcv_calendarMode="month"
    app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="saturday"/>
```

Java Code:

```
materialCalendarView.state().edit()
            .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 1, 1)) // 1st February, 2016
            .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 1, 29)) // 29th February, 2016
            .commit();
```

Here calendar should show **February 2016**. It shows days and dates information correctly but calendar Header shows always **current month and year** (image added).

[image: Calendar header shows **January 2017**]

How can I fix this problem?.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research I got a solution from their [documentation](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION.md#header) (in **Header** section).

My `onCreateView()` method are given below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_view, container, false);

    materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    final Calendar firstDate=Calendar.getInstance();
    firstDate.set(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);  // 1st February, 2016
    Calendar lastDate=Calendar.getInstance();
    lastDate.set(2016, 1, 29, 0, 0, 0);  // 29th February, 2016

    materialCalendarView.state().edit()
            .setMinimumDate(firstDate) // 1st February, 2016
            .setMaximumDate(lastDate) // 29th February, 2016
            .commit();

    materialCalendarView.setTitleFormatter(new TitleFormatter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence format(CalendarDay day) {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.US); //"February 2016" format

            String monthAndYear = simpleDateFormat.format(firstDate.getTime());

            return monthAndYear;
        }
    });


    materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(this);
    materialCalendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(this);

    return view;
}
```

I'm not sure is it the best practice or not, but it solved my issue. If there is another good approach to solve this problem please give your solution.

Answer (score -1):

In there documentation they said they do not gurantee that modification will retain... under heading **major change 1.4.0**

Comment: so? what should I do now?

Comment: In there documentation they said they do not gurantee that modification will retain... under major change 1.4.0

Comment: Can you please post the link of the documentation for ready reference for the OP?